# получение данных с jsp формы, при использовании составного(композитного) ключа в модели

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, form

Добрый день. Я совсем новичек, и уперся в несколько проблем в своем небольшом проекте на Java.

**Суть проблемы: не получается получить данные с формы на вьюхе, чтобы они корректно сохранились в БД.**

Возможно кто-то подскажет, если не решение, то куда посмотреть примеры толковые, или что почитать, что бы реализовать такую вещь? Буду крайне благодарен!

В кратце: для доступа в БД используется hibernate 4.3.11.Final, для шаблона MVC - Spring 4.2.5.RELEASE, выводится все с помощью JSP. 
Есть таблица ORDER_LIST (заказы), есть таблица PRODUCTS(продукты). У одного заказа может содержаться множество продуктов с разным количеством и разной ценой, это организовано с помощью дополнительной таблицы ORDER_LIST_PRODUCTS, где в качестве ключа выступает комбинация ID заказа и продукта.

схема вышеизложенного (экран 1 /* я извиняюсь за размер картинки, и за то, что все пришлось слепить в одну, но новичку больше 1 в пост нельзя заливать :( */): [image: общая схема]

как это должно выглядеть на вьюхе:
1) список заказов, и содержащихся в нем продуктов (экран 2). Эта часть реализована и работает.

2) после нажатия кнопки "новый заказ", появляется попап с формой (экран 3) По нажатию на "добавить изделие" получаем новую строку в форме с количеством и ценой (данная опция реализована через jQuery). По нажатию кнопки "Сформировать" - отправляем введенные данные на сервер и обрабатываем.

код model.orders.Order

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_LIST")
public class Order implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2205894374817474266L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Seller.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "SELLER", nullable = false)
private Seller seller;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Buyer.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "BUYER", nullable = false)
private Buyer buyer;

@NotNull
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<OrderProducts> orderProducts = new ArrayList<>();

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATE_OPERATION", nullable = false)
private java.util.Date dateOperation;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = OrderStatus.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_STATUS", nullable = false)
private OrderStatus orderStatus;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "comment")
private String comment;

геттеры/сеттеры....
```

код model.orders.OrderProducts

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_LIST_PRODUCTS")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.order", joinColumns =     @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.product", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))

})
public class OrderProducts implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8690354876196823857L;

@EmbeddedId
private OrderProductsId pk = new OrderProductsId();

@Column(name = "PRICE_PRODUCT")
private Double priceProduct;

@Column(name = "COUNT_PRODUCT")
private Integer countProduct;

геттеры + сеттеры .....
```

код model.orders.OrderProductId

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderProductsId implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2071195384942292086L;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Product product;

геттеры + сеттеры ...
```

собственно JSP с попапом:

```
<%-- Modal --%>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">


            <div class="modal-header panel-heading panel-info">

                    <span class="lead">
                        <%--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>--%>
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">НОВЫЙ ЗАКАЗ</h3>
                    </span>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <form:form modelAttribute="order" method="POST">
                    <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>



                    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                        <label for="seller" class="control-label">Продавец</label>
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="seller" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                        <form:select path="seller"  class="selectpicker form-control" overflow="hidden"  id="seller">
                            <form:options items="${sellerlist}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="fullName" />
                        </form:select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                        <label for="buyer" class="control-label">Покупатель</label>
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="buyer" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                        <form:select path="buyer"  class="selectpicker form-control" overflow="hidden" id="buyer">
                            <form:options items="${buyerlist}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="fullName" />
                        </form:select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group form-group-lg" id="fields">
                        <label for="xxx" class="control-label">Товары к поставке</label>


                        <div class="controls">

                            <c:forEach items="${order.orderProducts}" var="orderProduct" varStatus="counterObj" >

                        <div class="row voca">

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <form:select class="selectpicker form-control" path="orderProduct[${counterObj.index}].pk.product" overflow="hidden" id="xxx">
                                    <%--<optgroup label="${productlist.product.id_categories}">--%>
                                    <form:options items="${productlist}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="modelName" />
                                    <%--</optgroup>--%>
                                </form:select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="input-group spinner">
                                <form:input type="text" class="form-control spin" value="1" min="1" max="999" path="orderProduct[${counterObj.index}].countProduct"/>
                                <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default plusType" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default minusType" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="right col-md-1 vcenter">
                                <span>шт.</span>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <form:input class="form-control price" placeholder="Цена" name="price" type="text" pattern="\d+((,|\.)\d{1,2})?" path="orderProduct[${counterObj.index}].priceProduct" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="right col-md-2 buttons_bot_right vcenter">
                                <span class="sum_price">0</span> <span>руб.</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="right col-md-1 buttons_bot_right">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn main_color btn-add">
                                        <img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/Icon_Add.png'>
                                    </button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                            </c:forEach>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="buttons_bot_right vcenter margin_right_74">
                                <span>ИТОГО :  </span><span class="totalSum">0</span> <span>руб.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                        <label for="comment" class="control-label">Дополнительная информация</label>
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="comment" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                        <form:textarea class="form-control textaria_vertical" rows="9" id="comment" placeholder="Заполните условия сделки" path="comment" />

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                        <label for="orderStatus" class="control-label">Статус операции</label>
                        <div class="has-error">
                            <form:errors path="orderStatus" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                        <form:select path="orderStatus" class="selectpicker form-control" overflow="hidden" id="orderStatus">
                            <form:options items="${orderstatus}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="orderType" />
                        </form:select>
                    </div>



                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-lg buttons_bot_right margin_right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg cancel_button" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg save_button main_color">Сохранить</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>

            </form:form>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: итак комплексная проблема была решена. Возможно ответ поможет такому же новичку, как и я. 
Имеется связь many-to-many (в данном случае есть множество заказов - model.orders.Order, каждый из которых может содержать в себе несколько позиций изделий - model.products.Product, с различной ценой и количеством), которая реализуется посредством сторонней таблицы с дополнительными полями - model.orders.OrderProducts.

Эта сущность согласно советам опытных товарищей ([ссыль](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212058/how-to-make-a-composite-primary-key-java-persistence-annotation)) была несколько изменена. В частности составной натуральный первичный ключ был заменен на автогенерируемый. Для соблюдения уникальности комбинации значений составных полей в таблице использовалась конструкция UNIQUE(order_id, product_id), а в моделе @NaturalId над соответствующими полями.

генерация таблицы:

```
/* JOIN TABLE объединяет заказы и приборы*/
CREATE TABLE ORDER_LIST_PRODUCTS (
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
order_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
product_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
price_product DOUBLE NOT NULL,
count_product BIGINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE(order_id, product_id), 
CONSTRAINT FK_ORDER_LIST FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES ORDER_LIST (id),
CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTS FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES PRODUCTS (id)
);
```

код model.orders.OrderProducts

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_LIST_PRODUCTS")
public class OrderProducts implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NaturalId
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Order.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false)
private Order order;

@NaturalId
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Product.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false)
private Product product;

@Column(name = "PRICE_PRODUCT")
private Double priceProduct;

@Column(name = "COUNT_PRODUCT")
private Integer countProduct;

//геттеры, сеттеры, конструктор
}
```

код model.orders.Order

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_LIST")
public class Order implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Seller.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "SELLER", nullable = false)
private Seller seller;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Buyer.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "BUYER", nullable = false)
private Buyer buyer;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<OrderProducts> orderProducts = new HashSet<>(0);

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATE_OPERATION", nullable = false)
private java.util.Date dateOperation;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = OrderStatus.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_STATUS", nullable = false)
private OrderStatus orderStatus;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "comment")
private String comment;

public Order() {
}
//геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

"orphanRemoval = true" - говорит о том, что при удалении данной сделки, связанные с ней изделия, так же удалятся из таблицы ORDER_LIST_PRODUCTS.

Далее встает вопрос, как собрать данные, введеные пользователем в форму нового заказа, при условии, что позиций в заказе может быть различное(не прогнозируемое заранее) количество, которое пользователь определяет сам на лету. В сущности model.orders.Order у нас эти позиции хранятся в Set, но <del>нет никакого</del> мне не известно способа, как сказать форме, что все пришедшее в этом подблоке нужно собрать в множество. Но можно сказать, чтобы все это собралось во что-нибудь, что имеет доступ по индексу! в частности подойдут List или Map! Я предпочел Map, т.к. тогда не придется следить за корректностью индексов в форме (т.е. если у нас есть первый товар с индексом 0, после чего пользователь добавляет товар, второй индекс становится 1, потом удалиляет, потом опять добавляет и мы получаем два товара с индексами 0, 2. Это подходит для Map, а для List мы получим исключение). Для того, чтобы передать с формы данные в контроллер, был написан отдельный класс, для модели (по хорошему надо все классы разделять: Entity - для представления таблиц из БД, Model - для сбора информации с формы ввода данных. Теперь понятно, почему это надо делать :) ).

код model.orders.OrderModel

```
public class OrderModel implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1617932830823574986L;

private Long id;

private Seller seller;

private Buyer buyer;
// используется Map, чтобы собрать все позиции в заказе. Собственно это единственное отличие от класса model.orders.Order
private Map<Integer, OrderProducts> orderProducts;

private java.util.Date dateOperation;

private OrderStatus orderStatus;

private String comment;

public OrderModel() {
}
//геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

и соответственно JSP, где мы собираем наши данные для заказа, и хранящихся в нем позиций:

```
<div class="modal-body">

            <form:form modelAttribute="order" method="POST">
                <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>

                <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                    <label for="seller" class="control-label">Продавец</label>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="seller" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                    <form:select path="seller"  class="selectpicker form-control" overflow="hidden"  id="seller">
                        <form:options items="${sellerlist}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="fullName" />
                    </form:select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                    <label for="buyer" class="control-label">Покупатель</label>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="buyer" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                    <form:select path="buyer"  class="selectpicker form-control" overflow="hidden" id="buyer">
                        <form:options items="${buyerlist}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="fullName" />
                    </form:select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-group-lg" id="fields">
                    <label for="xxx" class="control-label">Товары к поставке</label>

                    <div class="controls">

                        <c:forEach items="${order.orderProducts.entrySet()}" var="orderProductEntry" >

                    <div class="row voca" data-subform-key="${orderProductEntry.key}">

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <form:select class="selectpicker form-control" path="orderProducts[${orderProductEntry.key}].product" overflow="hidden">

                                <form:options items="${productlist}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="modelName" />

                            </form:select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="input-group spinner">
                            <form:input type="text" class="form-control spin" value="1" min="1" max="999" path="orderProducts[${orderProductEntry.key}].countProduct"/>
                            <div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
                                <button class="btn btn-default plusType" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
                                <button class="btn btn-default minusType" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="right col-md-1 vcenter">
                            <span>шт.</span>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <form:input class="form-control price" placeholder="Цена" name="price" type="text" pattern="\d+((,|\.)\d{1,2})?" path="orderProducts[${orderProductEntry.key}].priceProduct" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="right col-md-2 buttons_bot_right vcenter">
                            <span class="sum_price">0</span> <span>руб.</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="right col-md-1 buttons_bot_right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn main_color btn-add">
                                    <img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/Icon_Add.png'>
                                </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                        </c:forEach>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="buttons_bot_right vcenter margin_right_74">
                            <span>ИТОГО :  </span><span class="totalSum">0</span> <span>руб.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                    <label for="comment" class="control-label">Дополнительная информация</label>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="comment" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                    <form:textarea class="form-control textaria_vertical" rows="9" id="comment" placeholder="Заполните условия сделки" path="comment" />

                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                    <label for="orderStatus" class="control-label">Статус операции</label>
                    <div class="has-error">
                        <form:errors path="orderStatus" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
                    <form:select path="orderStatus" class="selectpicker form-control" overflow="hidden" id="orderStatus">
                        <form:options items="${orderstatus}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="orderType" />
                    </form:select>
                </div>



                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group form-group-lg buttons_bot_right margin_right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg cancel_button" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg save_button main_color">Сохранить</button>
                </div>
                </div>

        </form:form>

        </div>
```

Далее остается получить эти данные в контроллере, которые представлены уже заполненным классом model.orders.OrderModel и переложить их в класс model.orders.Order для дальнейшего сохранения в БД. И Вот тут есть одна тонкость... 
На момент получения данных с формы, мы не знаем ID нашего заказа, что собственно логично, ведь его мы еще не сохранили в БД, которая и генерирует этот ID и поэтому в общем то не понятно как на JSP сказать, что вот все эти позиции относятся именно к данному заказу. В итоге при попытке сохранить его в БД мы получим ошибку, гласящую, что "ORDER_ID" не может быть null. Т.е. у нас по сути поле order в моделе model.orders.OrderProducts осталось не заполненным (и как сделать, чтобы оно заполнилось автоматически с формы заказа - я не знаю, если кто-то знает, был бы благодарен за подсказку!), поэтому его заполним ручками. 
Итак, для того, чтобы передать собранные данные в БД, нужно переложить их в сущность, ассоциированную с таблицей. Это сделано в контроллере:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/orders" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveProduct(@Valid OrderModel order, BindingResult result,
                          ModelMap model)  throws Exception{

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
    //обрабатываем ошибки валидации
    }

    //если все ок, перекладываем данные из модели в класс ассоциированный с таблицей. Для этого я использовал дополнительный конструктор
    Order orderDb = new Order(order);
    orderService.saveOrder(orderDb);

    //устанавливаем нужные флаги, выкидываем сообщение для пользователя, что все прошло ок, и т.д.

    return "orders";
}
```

добавляем в класс model.orders.Order конструктор, чтобы переложить данные из класса model.orders.OrderModel

```
public Order(OrderModel modelView) {
    this.seller = modelView.getSeller();
    this.buyer = modelView.getBuyer();
    this.dateOperation = modelView.getDateOperation();
    this.orderStatus = modelView.getOrderStatus();
    this.comment = modelView.getComment();

    // перекладываем позиции из Map в Set
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, OrderProducts> entry : modelView.getOrderProducts().entrySet()) {
        OrderProducts trueOrderProduct = entry.getValue();
    // каждому экземпляру OrderProducts устанавливаем в поле order текущую сделку. Тогда при сохранении Hibernate будет знать, к каком id привязывать эту позицию и все пройдет гладко
        trueOrderProduct.setOrder(this);
        this.orderProducts.add(trueOrderProduct);
    }
}
```

На этом пока все. Надеюсь если сюда забредет более опытный товарищ, он укажет на недостатки в данном подходе, или предложит какое-то более оптимальное решение.

С уважением